# Take profit/Stop loss right on opening candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I have been trying to make a stop loss and take profit for my strategy but always find myself at the same problem

My take profit signals are literally on the same candle as where the trade opens and they are not affected if I change the tp amount

Here is the code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("sma")

//dropdown menu to change the values of the EMA periods, stop loss, and take profit levels:
emaShortPeriod = input(100, minval=1)
emaLongPeriod = input(150, minval=1)
stopLoss = input(100, minval=0)
takeProfit = input(5, minval=0)

//use the input values to define the EMA series:
emaShort = sma(close, emaShortPeriod)
emaLong = sma(close, emaLongPeriod)

//plot the EMA series on the chart:
plot(emaShort, title="EMA (short period)", color=color.green)
plot(emaLong, title="EMA (long period)", color=color.orange)

//use the input values to define the long and short entry signals:
longEntry = crossover(emaShort, emaLong)
shortEntry = crossover(emaLong, emaShort)

//plot the long and short entry signals on the chart:
plotchar(longEntry, "Long Entry", "▲", location.top, color = #00FF00, transp = 0)
plotchar(shortEntry, "Short Entry", "▼", location.top, color = #FF0000, transp = 0)

//function to generate market orders when the entry signals are triggered:
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=longEntry)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=shortEntry)

//function to generate stop loss and take profit levels for the strategy:
strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Long", profit=takeProfit)
strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Short", profit=takeProfit)
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Long", loss=stopLoss)
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Short", loss=stopLoss)
```

And a picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5elqB.png)

Just expecting the TP and SL to work normally...

Comment: By default, your TP is set to 5. What is 5? Is it 5%, 5 pips or something else?

Comment: Well it is percent, but I found out how to do it and wrote an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

*I just started coding so sorry if this explination is not top tier*

1. When defying the stoplosspercent and the takeprofitpercent, with input, I was unaware that int numbers in the code have to be bigger that what you would ever input in the drop down menu.
   So for example if my code looks like this:

   stopLossPercent = input(2, minval=0, maxval=200)
   takeProfitPercent = input(2, minval=0, maxval=200)

I will not be able to set my stop loss or take profit above 2 without running into errors on the chart, but if I change it and set it too 200 for example:

```
stopLossPercent = input(200, minval=0, maxval=200)
takeProfitPercent = input(200, minval=0, maxval=200)
```

Then anything below 200 will work. I do not think you need a minval or maxval, but I just use it.

For the rest of the code to calculate the take profits and stop loss I made 4 variables:

```
stopLossPriceOne
takeProfitPriceOne
stopLossPricetwo
takeprofitPricetwo
```

One was used to calculate long TP and SL. Two was used for short.
I just used a very simple mathematics to calculate it...:

```
entryPrice = strategy.position_avg_price
stopLossPriceOne = entryPrice / 100 * (100 - stopLossPercent)
takeProfitPriceOne = entryPrice / 100 * (100 + takeProfitPercent)
stopLossPricetwo = entryPrice / 100 * (100 + stopLossPercent)
takeprofitPricetwo = entryPrice / 100 * (100 - takeProfitPercent)
```

The entryPrice is ofc where you start the trade

And then my exits:

```
strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=stopLossPriceOne, 
limit=takeProfitPriceOne)
strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", stop=stopLossPricetwo, 
limit=takeprofitPricetwo)
```

I hope this helps any new pinescript coders like me.

Here is the entire code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("sma")

//dropdown menu to change the values of the SMA periods, stop loss, and 
take profit levels:
smaShortPeriod = input(100, minval=1)
smaLongPeriod = input(150, minval=1)
stopLossPercent = input(200, minval=0, maxval=200)
takeProfitPercent = input(200, minval=0, maxval=200)

//use the input values to define the SMA series:
smaShort = sma(close, smaShortPeriod)
smaLong = sma(close, smaLongPeriod)

//plot the SMA series on the chart:
plot(smaShort, title="SMA (short period)", color=color.green)
plot(smaLong, title="SMA (long period)", color=color.orange)

//use the input values to define the long and short entry signals:
longEntry = crossover(smaShort, smaLong)
shortEntry = crossover(smaLong, smaShort)

//plot the long and short entry signals on the chart:
plotshape(longEntry, "Long Entry", shape.arrowup, location.top, 
color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(shortEntry, "Short Entry", shape.arrowdown, location.top, 
color=color.red, transp=0)

//function to generate market orders when the entry signals are 
triggered:
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=longEntry)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=shortEntry)

//function to generate stop loss and take profit levels for the 
strategy:
entryPrice = strategy.position_avg_price
stopLossPriceOne = entryPrice / 100 * (100 - stopLossPercent)
takeProfitPriceOne = entryPrice / 100 * (100 + takeProfitPercent)
stopLossPricetwo = entryPrice / 100 * (100 + stopLossPercent)
takeprofitPricetwo = entryPrice / 100 * (100 - takeProfitPercent)

strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=stopLossPriceOne, 
limit=takeProfitPriceOne)
strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", stop=stopLossPricetwo, 
limit=takeprofitPricetwo)
```

[Out Come](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKjMG.png)